# Cypress dynamic test crashes even in headless mode after certain number of iterations

Tags: testing, dynamic, crash, cypress, headless

I have a dynamic test that crashes after certain amount of iterations even when ran in headless mode.

In GUI mode it is quite obvious that over time the iterations slow down the browser and eventually crash it with the Aw, Snap! alert...

I have a data structure in .ts file. There's in total 11 iterations each creating 3 its...
The last of the 3 it's has a loop which iterates 10 times and executes few simple commands in each of the 11 iterations... I wonder if this could be a cache memory issue or why is it crashing even in CLI.

It doesn't crash the tests but rather just freezes the whole process. I understand that it would eventually happen in GUI mode as it is not meant for running long specs. Don't understand why it is happening in CLI.

I also changed any for loops for lodash _.times method as I heard it uses less resources...

Thank you in advance.

Tried to use lodash _.times instead of for loops and simplify the tests in general.

Expecting to run the whol spec file without problems in CLI.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example as right now it's unclear. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example